# jasmine throws "Cannot find module" when using require.main.require

Tags: node.js, jasmine, require

I'm using `require.main.require` in a node module to require another module to avoid relative paths.

jasmine will throw a not found exception when I test that module.

Is there anyway to keep using require.main.require? Any best practice?

Answer (score 0):

in case someone is looking for the answer:

require.main.require points to the root file, in this case, to Jasmin (not your app.js, etc). You need to create a **jasmine helper** that overrides your require.main.require function like so:

```
const path = require('path');

require.main.require = function(pathName) {
  //path to root app:
  const newPath = path.join(__dirname, '../', pathName);

  return require(newPath);
}
```